# How to package bower_components with only required resources?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower

I'm using Bower and Grunt on my application. Thus, I have a `bower_components` directory with several sub-directories, containing all my dependencies.

Currently, on my Gruntfile.js, I have something like that:

```
    copy: {
        bower: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'app/',
                    dest: 'dist/',
                    src: [ 'bower_components/**/*' ]
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
```

which means that I copy everything under `bower_components` to finally package my application. The problem is that I don't need everything under this directory, for example there are non minified JS, resources, documentation, etc.

Is there a way to make an intelligent filter that only takes the required elements in the `bower_components` directory (i.e. without selecting the files myself)?

Am I missing some good practices regarding the packaging of an application with bower and grunt?

Thanks

ps: as it is for an intranet application, I prefer not to use CDN.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: Not really. In fact we now have a specific tool that takes all the JS files required by the application and merge them in a central `app.js` file that contains all the application and its dependencies.

Comment: Same problem here but it doesn't seem to be solved somewhere.